# Dealing with Twitter API 1.1 update_with_media ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, twitter, twitter-oauth

i'm using as3 for my current project, login, post status to twitter is already done.. but i have problem with update_with_media. Here's the flow of my program. On other screen call it CaptureWebcam, user can capture pic from webcam but can't save it to user computer. And if user open share to twitter screen, there's popup to login and image from CaptureWebcam screen passed to twitter screen, and ready to upload and it failed to post... i don't know whats wrong with my code

here's my code, i'm using iotashan library

```
private function uploadImage(Image()):void {
            var myEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var urlRequest:URLRequest;
            var multipartLoader:MultipartURLLoader = new MultipartURLLoader();
            var urlHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader();

            var oAuth:OAuthRequest;
            var consumer:OAuthConsumer;
            var twitterRequestUrl:String;
            var headerValue:String = "";
            var auth_header:URLRequestHeader;
            var param:Object;
            var vid:Video;

            //var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
            var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(CaptureWebcam.vid.width, CaptureWebcam.vid.height, true, 0xFFFFFF);
            //var byteArray:ByteArray = myEncoder.encode(new Bitmap(new Turtle()).bitmapData);
            var byteArray:ByteArray = myEncoder.encode(bitmapData);

            var drawRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,image.width, image.height);
            bitmapData.draw(image, new Matrix(), null, null, drawRect, true);

            trace("upload test");
            //header create
            twitterRequestUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json";
            consumer = new OAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            oAuth = new OAuthRequest(OAuthRequest.HTTP_MEHTOD_POST, twitterRequestUrl, null, consumer, null);
            urlRequest = new URLRequest(oAuth.buildRequest(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()));
            //

            /*
            urlRequest = twitterRequestUrl;
            urlRequest.contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + UploadPostHelper.getBoundary();
            urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            urlRequest.data = UploadPostHelper.getPostData(file, byteArray);
            urlRequest.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader( 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache' ) );

            urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY
            urlLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, onStatusDelivered);
            urlLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onStatusChanged);
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleUploadComplete);
            urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);
            urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
            */


            /*
            multipartLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleUploadComplete);
            multipartLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            multipartLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSequrityError);
            multipartLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, onStatusDelivered);
            */

            /*
            headerValue = createHeaderValue(oAuth);
            auth_header = new URLRequestHeader("Authorization", headerValue);
            multipartLoader.requestHeaders.push(auth_header);
            multipartLoader.addVariable("status" , "test");
            multipartLoader.addFile(byteArray, 'image.jpg', 'media[]');
            multipartLoader.load("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json");
            */


            var signedData:String = oauth.getSignedRequest( URLRequestMethod.POST, "https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json", null );
            var authHeaderValue:String = createAuthorizationHeader( new URLVariables( signedData ) );

            // create multipart loader

            var multipartLoader : MultipartURLLoader = new MultipartURLLoader();
            multipartLoader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, handleUploadComplete );   
            multipartLoader.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError );
            multipartLoader.addEventListener( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError ); 

            // add headers

            var auth_header : URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader( "Authorization", authHeaderValue );
            multipartLoader.requestHeaders.push( auth_header );

            // add requeried data

            multipartLoader.addVariable( "status" , twitter_msg );
            multipartLoader.addFile( byteArray, 'image.jpg', 'media[]');    

            // load

            multipartLoader.load( "https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json" );
}

private function createAuthorizationHeader( _requestParams : Object, headerRealm : String = "" ) : String
{
var data:String = "";

    data += "OAuth "
    if ( headerRealm.length > 0)
    data += "realm=\"" + headerRealm + "\", ";

    for (var param : Object in _requestParams ) {
      // if this is an oauth param, include it
        if ( param.toString().indexOf("oauth") == 0){
        data += param + "=\"" + encodeURIComponent( _requestParams[param]) + "\", ";
        }
    }

    return data.substr( 0, data.length - 2);
}
```